# How to update RecyclerView using LiveData example:SeenCounter,CommentCounter,LikeCounter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

so I make social media app using RecyclerView, it has like button and like counter When MainActivity load OnCreate it will hit "http//test/getLikeCounter" to display like counter in my RecyclerView but when I click like button, it will hit my own API "http//test/setLikeCounter" and adding the counter in my database, but because it's not loading OnCreate method again it, so it's doesn't add my Like Counter in My RecyclerView, how should I do to Refresh my RecyclerView dynamically when I click Like Button?
Someone suggest to use LiveData, but how and where to implement it?

This is when I hit my API in OnCreate, it will hit "http//test/getLikeCounter" in WebAPI.java

```
webAPI_.rncryptorALLDEWA("Trending");
```

I received the data from hitting the API and convert the JSON file and send it back to MainActivity using EventBus

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MainActivity.EventStoredTrending event) {
    getTrendingMainActivity(event.SendDummyUrutan, event.SendTotalThread, event.SendDummyIDContent, event.SendDummyTitle, event.SendDummyPublishTime, event.SendDummyImageOri, event.SendDummyShortDescription, event.SendDummySeen, event.SendDummyComment, event.SendDummyLike);
}
```

After that, I set the value to my RecyclerView manually

```
public void createDummyData1UPDATE(int ReceivedDummyUrutan, int ReceivedTotalThread, String ReceivedDummyIDContent, String ReceivedDummyTitle, String ReceivedDummyPublishTime, String ReceivedDummyImageOri, String ReceivedDummyShortDescription, int ReceivedDummySeen, int ReceivedDummyComment, int ReceivedDummyLike, int ReceivedDummyisComment, int ReceivedDummyisLike, int ReceivedDummyisBookmark) {
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(ReceivedDummyIDContent, ReceivedDummyTitle, ReceivedDummyPublishTime, ReceivedDummyImageOri, ReceivedDummyShortDescription, ReceivedDummySeen, ReceivedDummyComment, ReceivedDummyLike, ReceivedDummyisComment, ReceivedDummyisLike, ReceivedDummyisBookmark,"x53535", "No Error"));

    if(ReceivedDummyUrutan ==  ReceivedTotalThread-1){
        ModelSectionHotTrendingNews modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX = new ModelSectionHotTrendingNews();
        modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setHeaderTitle("TRENDING NEWS");
        modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setAllItemsInSection(modelSingleHotTrendingNews);
        modelSectionHotTrendingNews.add(modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX);

        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews = v.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Single_HotTrendingNews);
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapterSectionHotTrendingNews = new AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews(getActivity(), modelSectionHotTrendingNews, listenerHotTrendingNews);
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(adapterSectionHotTrendingNews);
        //Optimized
        RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    }

}
```

When I click a like Button, I want to update to my RecyclerView so when the "LikeCounter" in the database increased, the RecyclerView updated dynamically

```
webAPI_.rncryptorCommentLikeBookmark("isLike", modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIdcontent(), modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIslike());
```

This is HotSectionAdapter.java

```
public class AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews;
private AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews.RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

public AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews, AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews.RecyclerViewClickListener mListener) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelSectionHotTrendingNews = modelSectionHotTrendingNews;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}



@Override
        public SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_section_hottrendingnews, null);
    return new SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
    ModelSectionHotTrendingNews modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX = modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position);

    //Set
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVSectionTitle.setText(modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getHeaderTitle());

    ArrayList singleSectionItems = modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getAllItemsInSection();

    //WOW
    AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews itemListDataAdapter = new AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews(mContext, singleSectionItems, mListener);
    //WOW

    final String sectionTitle = modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getHeaderTitle();
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.BTNHotTrendingNewsMore.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "click event on more, "+sectionTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, TabMoreHotActivity.class);
                // here you create put extra in new intent not the intent that you created

                intent.putExtra("MoreTrendingNews", modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position).getAllItemsInSection());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            } });




    /*Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/

    //SetRecyclerView
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelSectionHotTrendingNews.size();
    return itemCount;
}

public class SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView TVSectionTitle;
    protected ImageView BTNHotTrendingNewsMore;
    protected RecyclerView RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews;
    protected RecyclerView RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews;

    public SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TVSectionTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_SectionTitle);
        BTNHotTrendingNewsMore= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.BTN_HotTrendingNewsMore);
        RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Section_HotTrendingNews);
        RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewMore_Section_HotTrendingNews);
    }

}
```

}

This is HotSingleAdapter.java

```
public class AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews;

private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;


public AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews, RecyclerViewClickListener mListener) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelSingleHotTrendingNews = modelSingleHotTrendingNews;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

/*public void swap(ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> datas)
{
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.clear();
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.addAll(datas);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}*/

public void swap(ArrayList list){
    if (modelSingleHotTrendingNews != null) {
        modelSingleHotTrendingNews.clear();
        modelSingleHotTrendingNews.addAll(list);
    }
    else {
        modelSingleHotTrendingNews = list;
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//Container
@Override
public SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_single_hottrendingnews, null);
    return new SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v, mListener);
}

//Fill Container with Model Setter Getter
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
    final ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position);

    //Set
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameDate.setText(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGamedate());
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameTitle.setText(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGametitle());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGameimage()).into(singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGGameImage);
    /*singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGGameImage.setImageResource(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGameimage());*/

    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVSeenCounter.setText(String.valueOf(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getSeencounter()));
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVCommentCounter.setText(String.valueOf(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getCommentcounter()));
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVLikeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getLikecounter()));

    if(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getIscomment() == 0){
        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGCommentView.setImageResource(R.drawable.comment_off);
    }else if(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getIscomment() == 1){
        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGCommentView.setImageResource(R.drawable.comment_on);
    }

    if(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getIslike() == 0){
        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGLikeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_off);
    }else if(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getIslike() == 1){
        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGLikeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_on);
    }

    if(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getTrendingnewssaving() == 0) {
        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else if(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getTrendingnewssaving() == 1) {
        singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
    }

    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final int booltrendingnewssaving = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getTrendingnewssaving();

            final String idcontent = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getIdcontent();

            if (booltrendingnewssaving == 1){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn Off Saved News " + idcontent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
                modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(0);
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, false);*/
            } else if(booltrendingnewssaving == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn On Saved News " + idcontent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
                modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(1);
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, true);*/
            }
        }
    });



   /* Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/

    /*singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Passing Data to GameDescriptionActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GameDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ImagePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGameimage());
            intent.putExtra("NamePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedate());
            intent.putExtra("UrlPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getIdcontent());
            intent.putExtra("DescriptionPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGametitle());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.size();
    return itemCount;
}

public class SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView TVGameDate;
    TextView TVGameTitle;
    ImageView IMGGameImage;

    TextView TVSeenCounter;
    TextView TVCommentCounter;
    TextView TVLikeCounter;

    ImageView IMGSeenView;
    ImageView IMGCommentView;
    ImageView IMGLikeView;

    ImageView ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving;
    private RelativeLayout ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer;

    private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;


    public SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView, RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        TVGameDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDate);
        TVGameTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameTitle);
        IMGGameImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_GameImage);

        TVSeenCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_SeenCounter);
        TVCommentCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_CommentCounter);
        TVLikeCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_LikeCounter);

        IMGSeenView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_SeenView);
        IMGCommentView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_CommentView);
        IMGLikeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_LikeView);

        ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ICON_HotTrendingNewsSaving);
        ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ROW_HotTrendingNewsContainer);

        mListener = listener;
        ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
        IMGCommentView.setOnClickListener(this);
        IMGLikeView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ROW_HotTrendingNewsContainer:
                mListener.onRowHotTrendingNewsContainerClick(ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.IMG_CommentView:
                mListener.onRowCommentViewClick(IMGCommentView, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.IMG_LikeView:
                mListener.onRowLikeViewClick(IMGLikeView, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    void onRowHotTrendingNewsContainerClick(View view, int position);
    void onRowCommentViewClick(View view, int position);
    void onRowLikeViewClick(View view, int position);
}
```

}

This is HotSectionModel.java

```
public class ModelSectionHotTrendingNews implements Serializable {

private String headerTitle;
private ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> allItemsInSection;

public ModelSectionHotTrendingNews() {
}

public String getHeaderTitle() {
    return headerTitle;
}

public void setHeaderTitle(String headerTitle) {
    this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
}

public ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> getAllItemsInSection() {
    return allItemsInSection;
}

public void setAllItemsInSection(ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> allItemsInSection) {
    this.allItemsInSection = allItemsInSection;
}
```

}

This is HotSingleModel.java

```
public class ModelSingleHotTrendingNews implements Serializable {

private String idcontent;
private String gametitle;

private String gamedate;
private String gameimage;
private String gamedescription;

private int seencounter;
private int commentcounter;
private int likecounter;

private int iscomment;
private int islike;
private int trendingnewssaving;

private String value;
private String message;

public ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(String idcontent, String gametitle, String gamedate, String gameimage, String gamedescription, int seencounter, int commentcounter, int likecounter, int iscomment, int islike, int trendingnewssaving, String value, String message) {
    this.idcontent = idcontent;
    this.gametitle = gametitle;
    this.gamedate = gamedate;
    this.gameimage = gameimage;
    this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
    this.seencounter = seencounter;
    this.commentcounter = commentcounter;
    this.likecounter = likecounter;
    this.iscomment = iscomment;
    this.islike = islike;
    this.trendingnewssaving = trendingnewssaving;
    this.value = value;
    this.message = message;
}

public String getIdcontent() {
    return idcontent;
}

public void setIdcontent(String idcontent) {
    this.idcontent = idcontent;
}

public String getGametitle() {
    return gametitle;
}

public void setGametitle(String gametitle) {
    this.gametitle = gametitle;
}

public String getGamedate() {
    return gamedate;
}

public void setGamedate(String gamedate) {
    this.gamedate = gamedate;
}

public String getGameimage() {
    return gameimage;
}

public void setGameimage(String gameimage) {
    this.gameimage = gameimage;
}

public String getGamedescription() {
    return gamedescription;
}

public void setGamedescription(String gamedescription) {
    this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
}

public int getSeencounter() {
    return seencounter;
}

public void setSeencounter(int seencounter) {
    this.seencounter = seencounter;
}

public int getCommentcounter() {
    return commentcounter;
}

public void setCommentcounter(int commentcounter) {
    this.commentcounter = commentcounter;
}

public int getLikecounter() {
    return likecounter;
}

public void setLikecounter(int likecounter) {
    this.likecounter = likecounter;
}

public int getIscomment() {
    return iscomment;
}

public void setIscomment(int iscomment) {
    this.iscomment = iscomment;
}

public int getIslike() {
    return islike;
}

public void setIslike(int islike) {
    this.islike = islike;
}

public int getTrendingnewssaving() {
    return trendingnewssaving;
}

public void setTrendingnewssaving(int trendingnewssaving) {
    this.trendingnewssaving = trendingnewssaving;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So you have a response event in the MainActivity (with EventBus), that is the right place to add your element (which you got back from api) to your list and than refresh the adapter with notifyDataSetChanged.

you have two adapters, so in your mainActivity you need an instance of that adapter which u want to refresh with data.

```
adapter.setItems(list); 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

you could also add you new element to your list when you click the like, but than if u have some db error, your list will refresh, but you will out of sync with your db, so better to do this with the evenbus response.